# How to view chapter wise bookmarks in Okular?

Tags: pdf, evince, okular

Common pdf viewers like Document Viewer and Adobe Reader in Windows provide bookmarks for every chapter like so : 
[image]

Is there anyway to get the same feature in Okular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the "Contents" tab on the left.

[image: Okular and Contents tab]

Answer (score 0):

you can set a "special note" with a distinguishing icon marking the position of every bookmark. That way, you can have multiple bookmarks in a page and be able to remove any bookmark just removing the note.

Answer (score 0):

The **"Contents"** tab provides this information, but if the book does not have the bookmarks, this tab does not appear. Not to be confused with the "Favorites" tab

[image]